# Send Grid Attachment Not Working,

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments, sendgrid

Below code is provided, it sends file as an attachment, but file is empty i.e file does not have any data. Only I can see file name in email as an attachment, file have data which is saved, but in email it is empty.

```
$basePath = Yii::app()->basePath;

Data come from database table and here .xls file is created and saved in local folder
```

file_put_contents($basePath.'/../reports/excelreport.xls', $data);

```
$htmlbody = 'Content goes here';
```

Saved file path, which to send in email as an attachment.

```
$path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../reports/excelreport.xls';
$message = Yii::app()->sendgrid->createEmail();

$message->setHtml($htmlbody)
                ->setSubject('Reports Alert')
                ->addTo($email)
                ->setFrom('account@simplifyvms.net')
            ->setAttachment($path);
            Yii::app()->sendgrid->send($message);
?>
```

Comment: I can't get the file_put_contents correct. Anyone?

Comment: file_put_contents  creates file with values successfully.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant with the edit. That line just won't be code for me. I don't know why

Comment: you can ignore it, just comment it out.

Comment: the contents of attachment should be base 64 encoded as per the new V3 api.Check this link https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#attachments